# how to Make decision using Optimization algorithms

Tags: java, android, cloud

I'm developping an android application that scan the capacity of an android device (CPU, Memory, Battery) and the state of the network and data to make decision (make a computation offloading to the cloud or not).
In order to make an offloading you must make sure that all the informations (CPU, battery,...) is insufficient. for ex :
if (the battery capacity < 10% and current ram > 100 mb and ... etc )then 
    make offloading; // run the method in the Edge or cloud server
else
    local execution;

Until now I get all the informations about the device and the network, but i don't know how to make a decision. I think that the Optimization algorithms can help me, but i don't khow how to implement this algorithms in java.
Help me to take an aptimal decision.

Comment: Have you run tests to see what kind of hard limits you may be looking at? ie I can't do this computation with less than x RAM? This calculation will take x amount of time, maybe the battery level is too low? Network is down, maybe I can't send the computation to the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a set of rules/ algorithm like you mentioned, ie if (the battery capacity < 10% and current ram > 100 mb and ... etc )then make offloading. Its trivial to write that to your Java application, for example

```
    if((remaining_battery_perc<10)&&(average_ram_usage_mb>100)){

    //Start a new thread to offload the data

    }

    else{

    // local execution
    }

    //wait for the threads to finish their job
    // display the result
```

So provided there is server waiting for your request that processes the data and send you result back, it would work. However you have to keep in mind that offloading repeatedly can also consume significant energy depending on the bandwidth and amount of data you need to transmit.

If you do not have the offloading algorithm, its a open problem yet, one way to solve them would be to model them as [Markov Decision Process (MDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) and solve it to get the decision rules.